# Running Linux system commands from Ruby script

Tags: ruby, linux, system

I have the following Ruby script that creates a Debian package, which works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

  dest = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../build"
  package = "foo"

  [
    "cd #{dest} && tar czvf data.tar.gz bin console data.sql etc filter install.rb",
    "cd #{dest} && tar czvf control.tar.gz control",
    "cd #{dest} && echo 2.0 > debian-binary",
    "cd #{dest} && ar -cr #{package}.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz",
    "cd #{dest} && mv #{package}.deb ..",
    "cd #{dest} && rm data.tar.gz control.tar.gz",
  ].each do |command|
    puts command
    system(command)
  end
```

Is there a way in Ruby where I can leave off the "**cd #{dest} &&**" part of each command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dir.chdir(dest) do
  # code that shall be executed while in the dest directory
end
```

`Dir.chdir` when invoked with a block will change to the given directory, execute the block and then change back.

You can also use it without a block, in which case it will never change back.

Comment: Sweet.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use `Dir.chdir`:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

  dest = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../build"
  package = "foo"

  Dir.chdir dest
  [
    "tar czvf data.tar.gz bin console data.sql etc filter install.rb",
    "tar czvf control.tar.gz control",
    "echo 2.0 > debian-binary",
    "ar -cr #{package}.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz",
    "mv #{package}.deb ..",
    "rm data.tar.gz control.tar.gz",
  ].each do |command|
    puts command
    system(command)
  end
```